# Is there a measure for degree of reticulation in a phylogenetic network?

Tags: evolution, bioinformatics, phylogenetics, network, horizontal-gene-transfer

When working with phylogenetic networks, how does one talk about reticulate (i.e., web-like) the branches are? Is there a standard measure of this?

Comment: biostars.org may have some phd students that deal with that alot.